# Send email at a specific time - CRON jobs PHP

Tags: php, email, cron

Well basically i need to send emails at a specific time saved in a database, and the emails are registered in a different timestamps, the only issue here, is that i have a cron that executed for every hour, and the question here how to send a email for that's been scheduled at a different time as the cron been executed?

Comment: Do I understand your question to mean that the cron fires at `10:00, 11:00, 12:00, ...` and you want the emails to be sent at `10:13, 10:55, 11:44` for example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using plane timestamps you can just check if the sendDate is 'less than or equals' (lte) the current time. (if not use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to transform your datestring into a timestamp)

```
if($sendAt <= time()) {
    //send mail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usually task runner cron jobs are run much more frequent than once an hour. Try setting it to once every 5 minutes. That cron runs a job that checks db if there are any unsent emails that match the time between now and the last cron job (now - 5 mins) and sends them. the more specific timing you want the more often you need to run you job.